# How to set laravel 5.3 logout redirect path?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is there no elegant solution to redirect to a specific page after logging out in Laravel 5.3?

The function being called is from the trait **AuthenticatesUsers**:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

This is a default function from the core of laravel. So I have to override the whole function I cannot edit the core.
But isn't there a more simpler solution, cause it feel like overkill to manually logout, flush and regenerate again.

Worked the answers out in an article:
https://codeneverlied.com/how-to-set-logout-redirect-path-in-laravel-5-8-and-before/

Comment: What changes you want to do  ?

Comment: return redirect()->route('yourroute');

Comment: I hope on something simple that I can set in my LoginController something like `protected $logoutRedirectPath = 'my/path/';` but then logout method should have been `return property_exists($this, 'logoutRedirectPath') ? $this->logoutRedirectPath : '/';`

Comment: You should be able to use something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797433/how-to-change-the-redirect-url-when-logging-out

Comment: @AndyHolmes I hoped for this, but that doesn't work in 5.3 anymore. See the method that is being called.

Comment: Well, that's crap. I wonder why he removed it :/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is how I did it. In Auth\LoginController you have:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Change it to:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers {
    logout as performLogout;
}
```

Then, define a new `logout()` method in your LoginController:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->performLogout($request);
    return redirect()->route('your_route');
}
```

Sure, regular `logout()` method in that trait has only 3 lines (used to log users out of the system) so you can copy them to your method, but you should always follow the DRY principle (don't repeat yourself) and re-use as much code as you can.

Comment: Hi @avram, I have a question regarding the syntax in `use … { … as … }`. It looks like a bit of import/deconstucting. Do you know what is the name of this syntax/pattern? Thanks for your help, it works on the project I’m working on!

Comment: @meduz' I'm not quite sure how it's called, I've just found it in the PHP docs:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict

Comment: The only thing that is not mentioned  is including ``use Illuminate\Http\Request;`` in the LoginController.

Comment: Works for me in Laravel 8 as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 64):

## Laravel > 5.7

The accepted answer is fine, but you can completely bypass touching any of the logout logic by simply overwriting the `loggedOut` method:

```
// App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
protected function loggedOut(Request $request) {
    return redirect('/where/ever/you/want/to/go');
}
```

Comment: No worries. Just did a bit of digging around the source code

Comment: Works in 5.6 too

Comment: Hi, may I ask in which file I should override this method?

Comment: Probably, the only done-the-right-way answer here! Make sure the Request namespace is included in the Controller, which is: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: This is the proper answer.

Comment: @Hatef it's good for laravel 5.7+ but the question was for laravel 5.3 in which this answer is just wrong. But good to mention here, since many people will end up here.

Comment: Great answer! If you don't really need the Request in the function, actually you can remove the parameters, it still works properly...

Answer (score 15):

I would inherit `LoginController` and override the `logout` function coming from the trait in there:

**LoginController.php** -> leave that as it is.

**MyLoginController.php**:

```
class MyLoginController extends LoginController {

protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/goodbye';

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect($this->redirectAfterLogout);
    }
}
```

Of course, you should remember to update your Auth routes accordingly.

Comment: Was already using this. But no need to extend LoginController since controllers are open for modification. Just add the method to LoginController. Cause the method is in a trait that's used in the LoginController. This seems to be the solution, a redirect is not being triggered inside an event so events isn't an option

Comment: You're right, it's perfectly fine to define the `logout` override in the LoginController itself, I just like to keep stuff that didn't come "built-in" in my own separate files.

Comment: works like a charm in laravel 5.3, but you can directly edit the LoginController and override the logout method - anyway it would be nice if it would be implemented like the redirect after successfull login

Comment: @Kaloyan Doichinov, It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Answer (score 10):

I'm using **Laravel-5.2**, what I used was:

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Make sure you have imported:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

In your controller.

Comment: I was affraid of that. I think it's pretty ugly. It should have been possible to just add a property to the LoginController (AuthController in 5.2) with something like `protected $logoutRedirectPath = 'path';`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. May I know it's source if possible (or if you remember?), +1 for you my friend

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy sorry, I dont remember now, as its been years :)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming someone is viewing it now a days and the version of the laravel they are using is 5.7

Add this line in LoginController.php

```php
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->to('/your-route');
}
```

This assumes you are using the out of the box authentication module provided by laravel

Comment: Do not forget to add the Auth class, use Auth;

Comment: Confirmed at Laravel 6.7

Answer (score 6):

The Auth::routes method in laravel 5.3 registers a POST route for /logout instead of a GET route. This prevents other web applications from logging your users out of your application. To upgrade, you should either convert your logout requests to use the POST verb or just register your own GET route for the /logout URI by adding this route to the file Routes/web.php:-

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

and it should work fine and redirect you to the '/' directory as it's defined in the LoginController.php

Quoted from:-

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Comment: Thanks this was very helpfull

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to override logout trait at `LoginController` in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` like this

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->route('you_route_name');
}
```

Comment: wondering why you have just 3 upvotes, most brilliant and smart choice.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('logout', function (){
Auth::logout();
return redirect('your URL');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Every logout action fires an event `Events\Logout`. You can create a listener that listens to this event and add some logic to there. See more about listeners here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Comment: Found the event and it triggered. But something keeps it from redirecting. Inside the event I had `return redirect()->route('admin::login');` but it is not triggered. Event would be at least a bit cleaner. Also using a normal `header('Location: /');` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the out of the box AuthController add this variable to the top and then change the string to redirect wherever you want.

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/';
```

The AuthenticatesUsers class has a logout function that checks for this variable.

```
public function logout()
{
        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repeating logout code and to follow DRY, you may

- Add a custom logout route in *Auth/LoginController*, call
  `Auth::logout()` and return redirect to your path, or
- Add an *after*-middleware (say *redirectAfterLogout*) and add it to the logout route

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine, but you can completely bypass touching any of the logout logic by simply overwriting the loggedOut method:

```
protected function loggedOut(Request $request) {
    return redirect('/where/ever/you/want/to/go');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Laravel 5.8** find the below path :

**App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;*
```

write this function

```
public function logout(Request $request){
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/Where/You/want/to/redirect');;
}
```

Comment: Don't alter files in the vendor folder. When you run composer update, this change will be gone. This is not a good solution.

Comment: Thank you Tim van Uum. now i have posted a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Illuminate Support package: override logout method in LoginController.php

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 public function logout()
     {
         Auth::logout();

     return redirect('/wherever/you/want');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we review Laravel's default logout function's code on `AuthenticatesUsers` trait (which located under vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers for laravel 7) we will see a hard coded path for redirecting. It means we need to change the url from the source but editing files via vendor is a wrong way however traits provide us with a better way which we are in power of overriding the codes So just paste the all logout function's codes to LoginController page and change the redirect('/') function's parameter to any url you want.

Currently my code looks like those just place it in `LoginController`:

```
/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    if ($response = $this->loggedOut($request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new Response('', 204)
        : redirect('/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted it to redirect the user to the home page `'/home'` after logging out but it kept redirecting him to login page
The reason was that the default `HomeController` used the auth middleware

I had to remove this line `$this->middleware('auth');` from the `__construct` method

Answer (score 0):

I just updated an old website to Laravel 5.3. This involved adding the 4 new Auth controllers from [Laravel Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.3/app/Http/Controllers/Auth) as advised in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0).

Three of new controllers: RegisterController.php, LoginController.php and ResetPaswordController.php all contain a code block

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Simply change /home to the desired redirect location. At least that worked for me in Laravel 5.3 (data April 2021)

Answer (score 0):

**It'll work 100% on laravel 9.** When you manaully redirect to any route after logout.
import this classes at top of the **LoginController.**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

 protected function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush();
        Session::regenerate();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8+, try editing the redirect method in logout method on /vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticateUsers.php [Laravel-AuthenticateUsers.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcjlT.png)

Answer (score -5):

you can go to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`
in function `logout` change  `return redirect('/');` to your route address.

Comment: This is very bad practice! If you run `composer update` your change is gone. Never alter files in the vendor folder.